# Chrome css issue using token input jquery plugin

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm using jquery plugin token input for my dropdowns on this page 
http://www.connectweb.com.au/search.aspx

It works fine in firefox in that I can click the arrow and the dropdown opens with the contents and allows me to scroll up and down using the scrollbar.  However in IE and Chrome I cannot seem to scroll by moving the scroll bar up and down.  Its some css somewhere but I'm struggling to find out what..any css experts out there want to take a quick look? would be appreciated : -)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

​Hello please take a look at the https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/130

The issue happens to be with the the way IE handles scroll bars versus chrome or firefox.  The solution is to modify the inputtoken.js file as mentioned in the forum.

Here is the basic outline.

Declare a variable to hold the state

Check of the variable in the .blur event of the input_box

Add .mouseover, .mouseout to .dropdown
// 1. Keep track of mouse being over dropdown

```
var mouseOverDD;

// 2. IF the blur function

var input_box = $("<input type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\">")

.blur(function () {
    if (!mouseOverDD) {
        hide_dropdown();
        $(this).val("");
    }
})

// 3. Add over/out events

var dropdown = $("<div>")
    .addClass(settings.classes.dropdown)
    .appendTo("body")
    .hide()
    .mouseover(function(){
        mouseOverDD = true;
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        mouseOverDD = false;
    });
```

Comment: If you have a question of your own you need to ask a new question.